# How does the Graphics Pipeline work?

Tags: opengl, matrix, 3d

According to my research the graphics pipeline works like this:

Model Space

-> * Scalation/Translation/Rotation Matrices

World Space

-> * View Matrix

View/Camera Space

-> * Perspective Projection Matrix

Clip Space

-----> gives you NDC which are used by Rasterization

Could someone tell me if this is correct?
Is Clip Space the same as Projection Space?

Comment: http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/computing-pixel-coordinates-of-3d-point (and the following lessons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, but you are focusing only on the vertex shader stage. I think [this](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview) is a more general overview of a "graphics pipeline". That is what OpenGL offers you, however you don't need to use all stages, some stages are optional. A typical program will only use a vertex (Model=>World=>View=>...) and a fragment shader(texturing, lighting,...).

Moreover, you should note that your pipeline is a rasterizer pipeline. There are other methods ([Ray tracing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_%28graphics%29)).

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for! Helped alot